# Three.js create a valid Mesh from coordinates, indices, and material

Tags: three.js, geometry, mesh, shadow

I have data that contains arrays for *coordinates*, *indices*, and a *material*, which I'd like to represent as a `Mesh` in `Three.js`.

I have a valid `Scene` where I've defined `AmbientLight` and `DirectionalLight`.
When I use a simple `BoxGeometry`, I can see a red cube, with shadows, totally fine:

```
const geometry = new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = CompilePhongMaterial({ r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 255 });
const boxMesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
boxMesh.position.set(5, 0, 0);
boxMesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(boxMesh);
```

When I try to build my own `Mesh` using the data, I get a completely 'blacked out' `Mesh`.
The geometry looks valid in the `Scene`, but the `Material` appears black:

```
const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

const positionAttribute = new Float32BufferAttribute(data.coordinates, 3);
const indexAttribute = new Uint16BufferAttribute(data.indices, 1);
const material = CompilePhongMaterial({ r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 255 });

geometry.setAttribute("position", positionAttribute);
geometry.setIndex(indexAttribute);

let newMesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
newMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
newMesh.castShadow = true;
newMesh.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add(newMesh);
```

The `CompilePhongMaterial` function is a simple `Material` builder:

```
const CompilePhongMaterial = (materialColor) => {
const meshColor = new Color(materialColor.r / 255, materialColor.g / 255, materialColor.b / 255);

const newMaterial = new MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: meshColor,
  side: DoubleSide,
});

  return newMaterial;
};
```

I've tried looking into the `Objects` for the `BoxGeometry` `Mesh` as well as my own constructed `Mesh`, and both have the exact same properties when it comes to the material, i.e. the Color of the constructed `Mesh` is consoled out as **red**, but it appears **black** in the scene.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

When you do this, the geometry is empty and no normals can be computed.

Try to make it this way:

```js
const geometry = new BufferGeometry();

const positionAttribute = new Float32BufferAttribute(data.coordinates, 3);
const indexAttribute = new Uint16BufferAttribute(data.indices, 1);
const material = CompilePhongMaterial({ r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 255 });

geometry.setAttribute("position", positionAttribute);
geometry.setIndex(indexAttribute);
geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // move the line here
```